# Run command on all .JS files in a directory recursively?

Tags: indentation

Someone at my workplace committed non-indented JavaScript I have the VIM plugin [autoformat](https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat) installed and want to run `:Autoformat` on all .js files in my project directory, how would one do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your project directory is just a regular directory you could use `argdo`.

Navigate to the directory in your shell and open vim with `vim ./.*`. This will open all the files in the directory in vim's argument list. Then you can simply do

```
:argdo Autoformat <BAR> update
```

See [`:help :argdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargdo) for more info.

Comment: You can also populate the arglist via `:args`. e.g. `:args **/*.js`. You can also use backticks to execute a command to make this process quicker/better.  ``:args `ag --js -g ''` ``, ``:args `find . -type f -name '*.js'` ``, or ``:args `git diff --name-only HEAD^..HEAD` ``